# Insert record into another table

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

[image]

I have a table shown in picture. I want to enter the distinct agent_name and their total time values in another table. I tried this code for the sum of time

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME))) AS total FROM table name WHERE agent_name="name";
```

In another table, I want to show only agent name and their total time.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement "select the distinct agent_name and there total time values"

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME))), agent_name AS total FROM table name group by agent_name;
```

Comment: time not shown correctly.in above picture Mustafa Firoz have the two time and his total time should be 00:13:04. but when i run your code it display 201:05:25